# Why a vector is a (1,0) tensor?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

I am looking for some familiar examples of [Tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Examples)
 and I am wondering why a vector is a (1,0) tensor type?

That is it takes some covector and gives and scalar!! How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, $V$ is isomorphic to its double dual $V^{**},$ through the natural isomorphism $\varphi:V\rightarrow V^{**}$ given by $\varphi(x)(v)=v(x),$ where $x\in V$ and $v\in V^*.$ Hence, an element of $V$ can be seen as a linear functional that acts on covectors.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, the map $\varphi : V \to V^{**}$ is injective, so a vector can be viewed as a $(1,0)$-tensor. However, not every $(1,0)$-tensor will arise this way.

Comment: True, but since their link was talking about finite dimensions and tensors on infinite dimensional spaces is generally a harder concept, I elected to omit it.

Comment: How would you expand such a linear functional in a basis and relate it to the expansion of the vector in its basis? I asked a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4403485/990732