# Identifying tensor components as vector components

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, tensors

My understanding is that any vector $\bf{v}$ in a finite dimensional inner product space $(V,+,\cdot,\mathbb{F})$ can be represented by a (1, 0)-tensor, with the usual multilinear mapping definition of a tensor:

$\textbf{v} = T : V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \varphi \rightarrow T(\varphi)= \varphi(\textbf{v}) $ (which can easily be proven to be linear)

However, by picking a basis $B = \{\textbf{b}_1,...,\textbf{b}_n\}$ and it's dual basis $B^* = \{\textbf{e}^1,...,\textbf{e}^n\}\ \ $     (s.t. $\textbf{e}^j(\textbf{b}_i) = \delta_i^j$)...

We can expand the vector $\textbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n v^i\textbf{b}_i$ and identify its components of the vector as the $v^i$ by definition.

**Now**: I am trying to show that the tensor components $T^i=v^i$ equal the vector components, i follow this reasoning:

> We develop using the tensors linearity:
>
> $T(\varphi) = T(\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi_i\textbf{e}^i) =$
> $\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi_i T(\textbf{e}^i) = \sum_{i=1}^n\varphi_i T^i =$
> $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\varphi_i T^j\delta_j^i =$
> $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\varphi_i T^j\textbf{e}^i(\textbf{b}_j) = \\ $
> $\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi_i \textbf{e}^i(\sum_{j=1}^nT^j\textbf{b}_j) =$
> $\varphi(\sum_{j=1}^nT^j\textbf{b}_j)$
>
> Since $T(\varphi) = \varphi(\textbf{v}) =$
> $\varphi(\sum_{j=1}^nT^j\textbf{b}_j)$, ""we can apply"" $\varphi^{-1}$
> to the equation and get $\textbf{v} = \sum_{j=1}^nT^j\textbf{b}_j\ \ $
> thus showing the $T^i$'s to be the same as the vector components
> $v^i$, and justifying the defining of a vector as a (1,0)-tensor.

I however do not know whether or not every covector is invertible or not and therefore doubt this is a rigorous way of doing it. I am asking for any other better justification or correction

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are overthinking it. The tensor components $T^i$ are the numbers you get when you let the tensor eat the elements of the dual basis: $T^i=\boldsymbol{T}(\boldsymbol{e}^i)\,.$ In your case it is obvious that this gives $T^i=v^i\,.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back on this i find $T^i = T(e^i)=e^i(v) = e^i(v^jb_j)=v^je^i(b_j)=v^j\delta^i_j = v^i$